# Attempting to index data from CSV file, but get: TypeError: integer argument expected, got float instead

Tags: python, csv, datetime

```
with open (csvfile) as data:

    datareader = csv.reader(data , delimiter=',')
    next(data)
    for x in datareader:        
        tick = x[0]
        d = pd.to_datetime(x[1] , "%m/%d/%Y")
        t = pd.to_datetime(x[2] , "%H:%M")
        m = x[6]

std = datetime(2015,9,6,17,40)
etd = datetime(2015,9,11,16,36)

print ("Start Time:       ", std, "Value: ", m[std])
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\MyPrograms\anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\MyPrograms\anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 85, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "Z:/WORK/Programming/Python/Scripts/untitled1.py", line 64, in <module>
    print ("startTradeDate:       ", std, "Value: ", m[std])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

It's supposed to print out data "m" at the specified date and time, but it gives me the above error.  I don't understand how I'm supposed to pass an integer to it, when the only way is to pass a datetime index.  That is I'm trying to index the date and time from a csv, but no matter what I do it's failing to do that.

I guess I'm just failing to understand how to label and retrieve x/y co-ordinates from a CSV file and then being able to point to the location via python.  Does my problem make sense?  The above code is just one of my many failed attempts.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do? You posted  a part of a code and you posted the error with it. You need to provide a  [MCVE] .

Comment: The only thing that's missing from the code is the path to the csv file and the import section.

Comment: See, I can't reference 'm' at the specific date.  That's the issue.  I'm watching a youtube video or two about how to deal with spreadsheets, while they are informative, I'm not sure they will address my specific issue.

Comment: Well, I think I was slicing the data incorrectly.  It should read: "m[std:std]" It looks awkward but it appears to work.  But the data isn't outputting correctly.